# How do I get the firebase current user id (uid) in python?

Tags: python, firebase

I need to get the current user id.
In Javascript I use this to obtain the id

```
uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid // uid= ABO0Xc2E6KSDodEhenICkXF371x1
```

how do I get the uid in python
?

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to retrieve the user id without login or signup.

```
auth.current_user['localId']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)
print(user['localId'])
```

this will display the current firebase UID on output screen

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention a library, but all your other questions are using Pyrebase, so skimming over the documentation (which you should definitely be reading)...

```
# Get a reference to the auth service
auth = firebase.auth()

# Log the user in
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

# Get the user's idToken 
token = user['idToken']
```

Answer (score 0):

Resurfacing an old question, but looking in to the documentation of Pyrebase [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/7a652e6bd9d148da5ff6dbe7548c6d5d0dfa1109/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L111), I noticed that when you refresh the token, the userId is (compared to the other auth functions) retreived. So my solution is:

```
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("email", "pass")
user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])    
print(user['userId'])
```

EDIT:

I now see there is a 'localId' variable in the user object even before refreshing - as [@Abdul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8277825/abdul-moiz) indicated.