# Pyrebase, How to include UID inside of storage.child(path).download(outputfile)

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I am trying to use pyrebase to download a file from firebase storage. This file is located in customers/BoomMZrVfrOOOYa4JVibOJQoroT2/example.txt, I'm using this code to download it

```
firebaseConfig={'apiKey': "example",
                'authDomain': "example",
                'databaseURL': "example",
                'projectId': "example",
                'storageBucket': "example",
                'messagingSenderId': "example",
                'appId': "example",
                'measurementId': "example"}
firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
db = firebase.database()
auth=firebase.auth()
email = 'example@gmail.com'
password = 'password123'
login = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
storage = firebase.storage()        
storage.child('customers/DNOgkWW8yRUaEZXko2S2EPEIiBR2/k.txt').download(path="C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test", filename='k.txt')
```

This works when I allow read and write to anyone from firebase storage. I'm using these firebase storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /customers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
   }
  }
 }
```

This only allows users to download files from a folder named with their user ID. The problem is that i cannot downloaded files from firebase storage if it requires authentication in my rules. If authentication is not required then my code works.

EDIT:
I have changed my firebase rules to allow all authenticated users to login so that this is easier to debug. Here are my new rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /customers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
   }
  }
 }
```

I have also edited the code to a minimal example as was requested.

Answer (score 0):

The only information you can pass to the request is the path. Since you want to secure access on the UID of the user, that UID has to be part of the path to the file.

So you will have to:

1. Ensure that the user is signed in with Firebase Authentication
2. Pass the UID of the currently signed-in user in the path of the request

Since you hard-coded the UID of the user, I assume the user may not be signed in or you may be passing a UID value that doesn't match the current user.

Comment: In my real code I have logged in using firebase authentication, I just used this for demonstration purposes. I'm sorry im new to this but what do you mean by pass the UID of the currently signed-in user in the path of the request? Is it like how I am currently doing it with the path_on_cloud variable and the storage.child?

Comment: "In my real code I have logged in using firebase authentication" Instead of describing that in words, edit your question to show the actual [minimal-but-complete code that we can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright I have included this in the edit, Thank you for the help, please let me know if i am doing anything incorrectly. I have noticed that this works when I allow read access to non-authenticated users but as soon as i require authentication it does not work.

Comment: The problem is that you still use a hard-coded value for the UID: `DNOgkWW8yRUaEZXko2S2EPEIiBR2`. You need to get the UID of the logged in user. This seems relevant for doing that in Pyrebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134974/how-do-i-get-the-firebase-current-user-id-uid-in-python

Comment: `UID = auth.current_user['localId']`   and `storage.child(f'customers/{UID}/k.txt').download(path="C:\\Users\\nosec1\\Desktop\\gui", filename='k.txt')` still doesn't work.

Comment: If I allow unauthenticated users to download files the code works, but as soon as I require authentication this stops working.